# Accessing WebServer on Dev Box from Docker

Tags: docker, networking

I have a strange situation.  I am running docker local on my windows box.  When I fire up everything up my container can access everything but my local machine web server via HTTP/HTTPS.  Since this is a dev environment, is there a way to allow docker to access any HTTP/HTTPS URL? If not, how do I register my local stack machine with docker?

To better explain what I am seeing:
My local machine is bigbox.domain.com.
My web address I'm trying to hit is: https://bigbox.domain.com/demo/users

When I do a `wget` I get:

```
Resolving bigbox.domain.com (bigbox.domain.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘bigbox.domain.com’
```

But if I do a `wget` on say google.com, it works.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Could you explain showing the code? Maybe, you need to configure `extra_hosts`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts

Comment: There really isn't any code to show, I try to use `wget` web address and I can reach any machine but the one hosting the docker itself.